# registry Setting for ArcGIS 931 on Windows 7 PC

Tags: arcgis-9.3

I am having some issues with ArcGIS 9.3.1 instalation on Windows 7 PC. After installation, when I checked the regsitry setting, it shows: ArcInfo as entry (I chose the option of Arcview during install). it doesn't create other entries as well.

I have an installer that looks for LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ESRI\ArcGIS\InstallDir and it doesnt find these settings.

Is it possible that these entries have been removed and if that is the case, where does it save these settings in Windows 7 environment. Looking for some feedback.

Thanks
jay

Comment: Where is the problem? What are the issues except that registry does show some incorrect info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your Win7 a 64 bit system? If so what do you see when you check the 32 bit hive in the registry?